# recursive query sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SELECT": syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion, recursive-query

So I have the following recursive

```
WITH RECURSIVE length(len, id, ord) AS (
    SELECT 0, t.id, 1
    FROM temp t
    UNION
    SELECT len + compute(

        SELECT w2.nodeid
        FROM waypoint w2
        WHERE w2.ordinal = ord AND w2.wayid =t.id,

        SELECT w2.nodeid
        FROM waypoint w2
        WHERE w2.ordinal = ord + 1 AND w2.wayid =t.id

    ), t.id, w1.ordinal
    FROM waypoint w1, length, temp t
    WHERE w1.wayid = t.id AND w1.ordinal = ord + 1
),
SELECT *
FROM length
```

The issue is that I keep getting this error

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SELECT": syntax error

compute is just a user defined sqlite function that takes two node ids to compute the distance between them.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Remove comma between WITH end and the SELECT. Etc.

Comment: Tip of today: Build your query up step by step. Then you'll notice when you introduce an error. The above query has at least 5 several syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in `FROM waypoint w1, length, , temp t` two commas apeaer near each other.

Try this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE length(len, id, ord) AS (
    SELECT 0 as len, t.id, 1 as ord
    FROM temp t
    UNION
    SELECT (len + compute(

        SELECT w2.nodeid
        FROM waypoint w2
        WHERE w2.ordinal = ord AND w2.wayid =t.id,

        SELECT w2.nodeid
        FROM waypoint w2
        WHERE w2.ordinal = ord + 1 AND w2.wayid =t.id

    ) )as len, t.id, w1.ordinal as ord
    FROM waypoint w1, length, temp t
    WHERE w1.wayid = t.id AND w1.ordinal = ord + 1
),
SELECT *
FROM length
```

Comment: It was a typo when I was pasting it, I tried with this and still no luck

Comment: Maybe because of the needing alias. I update the answer try it again @saji

Comment: Still syntax error(s).

Comment: if you can, share sample data and query in https://sqliteonline.com/, Then I can have a better review @saji